# mkdir() error in wordpress: Permission denied ReduxCore

Tags: wordpress, permission-denied

I'm hosting a wordpress website on godaddy, but late renewal cause hosting is being remove, after i recover, i get this error:

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/mickaeladmin/public_html/en/wp-content/themes/getphoto/admin/redux-framework/ReduxCore/inc/class.redux_filesystem.php on line 104
```

and i found the line of the code is

```
elseif ( $action == 'copy' && ! isset( $this->filesystem->killswitch ) ) {
                    $res = $wp_filesystem->copy( $file, $destination, $overwrite, $chmod );
                    if ( ! $res ) {
                        $res = copy( $file, $destination );
                        if ( $res ) {
                            chmod( $destination, $chmod );
                        }
                    }
                }
```

can i know what is the error? and how to fix it?

Comment: try a chmod like 770 for the target folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly the error means that there are some missing permissions

you can change the user permission of a folder with an FTP Cllient. Detailed information can be found [here](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ftp/ftp_chmod.htm)

you should check the permissions and either set them on 775 or 664, Depends on what kind of permissions are needed precisly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: having same issue, i chmoded everything noo luck. what folder did you change permissions on? (im running on ubuntu server 18  Apache with php 7.2 )

Comment: @md123 are you still having problems?